# Why val_loss is too low but Test Root Mean Squared Error is higher?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am training LSTM where the dataset is of 17568 rows for monitored values for 2 months each with 5 minutes period.

The model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=70, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=10, verbose=1)], verbose=1, shuffle=False)
model.summary()
```

The code to calculate the RMSE is:

```
train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
# invert predictions
train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict)
Y_train = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_train])
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_test])
print('Train Mean Absolute Error:', mean_absolute_error(Y_train[0], train_predict[:,0]))
print('Train Root Mean Squared Error:',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_train[0], train_predict[:,0])))
print('Test Mean Absolute Error:', mean_absolute_error(Y_test[0], test_predict[:,0]))
print('Test Root Mean Squared Error:',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_test[0], test_predict[:,0])))
```

The training performances generated by the Keras model are:

```
 val_loss : 0.0017
 loss :  0.0019
```

While the RMSEs computed by hand are:

```
Train Mean Absolute Error: 10.814174578676965
Train Root Mean Squared Error: 13.792484521895835
Test Mean Absolute Error: 8.059164253166095
Test Root Mean Squared Error: 10.6127240648618
```

Please help me to understand where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`val_loss` and `loss` are computed during training on SCALED target.
While `mae` and `rmse` are computed post on INVERSESCALED target and these are the real performance.